# Material UI Theme Overrides how to correctly update gap between label and input

Tags: css, material-ui, material-design, overriding, themes

I'm trying to update my MUI themes using the `overrides` functionality.

This is what I have for my input field:

[image: Input Example]

I want to increase the gap between the label and the input field.

This is the `overrides` code that I have:

```
const overrides: Overrides = {
  MuiInput: {
    root: {
      backgroundColor: 'white',
      border: '1px solid #cdcfd1',
      borderRadius: 10,
      height: 50
    }
  },
  MuiInputBase: {
    root: {
      marginTop: 25
    }
  },
  MuiInputLabel: {
    asterisk: {
      '&$error': { color: '#eb131b' },
      color: '#eb131b',
      float: 'left',
      marginRight: 5
    },
    root: {
      '&$focused': {
        color: '#222',
        transform: 'translate(0, 0)'
      },
      color: '#222',
      fontSize: 16,
      fontWeight: 'bold',
      top: 0,
      transform: 'translate(0, 0)'
    },
    shrink: {
      transform: 'translate(0, 0)'
    }
  }
};
```

I want to change the `MuiInputBase` margin to `25` but it is being overridden by the following:

[image: CSS Output]

What is the correct way to update this via the theme overrides?

**Extra:** Here's a link to a Code Sandbox to play around with the issue: https://2gv94.csb.app/

Comment: Please give us a codesandbox to check this out!

Comment: Ok I'll get to work on that

Comment: @gionic here it is: https://2gv94.csb.app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add inside `overrides` and inside your `MuiInput`

```
formControl: {
  "label + &": {
    marginTop: "25px"
  }
}
```

Check the example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/divine-mountain-fftq4?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
MuiInput: {
  formControl: {
    "label + &": {
      marginTop: 25
    }
  }
},
```